# On the target of "not"

Tags: meaning, negation, antecedents

I would like to know the target of the word "not" in the following sentence.

> The problem is that Britons were never given a chance to vote on whether they wanted the CCTV cameras set up or **not**.

I wonder which of the following is a correct interpretation:

1. whether they wanted the CCTV cameras set up or (they did *not* want the CCTV cameras set up)
2. whether they wanted the CCTV cameras set up or (*not* set up)

Answer (score 2):

It is ambiguous - though there is hardly any difference in meaning, so it doesn't matter in practice.

Thinking about it, I find it very difficult to decide which interpretation I would favour. I *think* it would be the matrix verb (so *or did not want*) but I am not sure.

Comment: They may have indeed wanted the CCTV cameras - but not set up - rather simply delivered in their boxes so that set-up could be performed later -  very different meanings.

Comment: Yes @Brad, they could. And the Flying Spaghetti Monster could have gone round the world delivering presents last night. What people discussing language often seem to ignore is that pragmatics are as much a part of language as grammar.

Comment: @ColinFine Aw. So then where do I return the sieve?